# CMS applications as frameworks?

Tags: frameworks

I was posed this question the other day and didn't really know how to respond. Anyone here have any comments?

*Some CMS applications can be used as a frameworks, but it does not work the other way around.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not suggest using CMSes as frameworks if you're working on anything but trivial blogish/wordpress type websites which don't really need a whole lot of custom functionality.

CMS code is usually not extendable, following no coding conventions and crappy. Frameworks like Django and Zend are very high quality. You'll be able to actually make something useful in a reasonable amount of time instead of killing yourself trying to customize a CMS which wasn't made to be customized.